# Perl script.file handling issues

Tags: perl, unix

I have written a Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name;
my $ext = ".text";
my $subnetwork2;
my %files_list = ();
    opendir my $dir, "." or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
    my @files = readdir $dir;

sub create_files() {

    my $subnetwork;
    open(MYFILE, 'file.txt');
    while (<MYFILE>) {
        if (/.subnetwork/) {
            my @string = split /[:,\s]+/, $_;
            $subnetwork = $string[2];
        }
        if (/.set/ && (defined $subnetwork)) {
            my @string = split /[:,\s]+/, $_;
            my $file = $subnetwork . $string[1];
            open FILE, ">", "$file.text" or die $!;
            close(FILE);
        }
    }
    close(MYFILE);
}

sub create_hash() {
    foreach (@files) {
        if (/.text/) {

            open($files_list{$_}, ">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");

        }
    }
}

sub init() {
    open(MYFILE3, 'file.txt');
    while (<MYFILE3>) {
        if (/.subnetwork/) {
            my @string3 = split /[:,\s]+/, $_;
            $subnetwork2 = $string3[2];
            last;
        }
    }
    close(MYFILE3);
}

sub main_process() {

    init;
    create_files;
    create_hash;

    open(MYFILE1, 'file.txt');
    while (<MYFILE1>) {
        if (/.subnetwork/) {
            my @string3 = split /[:,\s]+/, $_;
            $subnetwork2 = $string3[2];
        }
        if (/.set/) {
            my @string2 = split /[:,\s]+/, $_;
            $file_name = $subnetwork2 . $string2[1] . $ext;
        }
        if (/.domain/ || /.end/ || ($. < 6)) {
            my $domain = $_;
            foreach (@files) {
                if (/.text/ && /$subnetwork2/) {
                    prnt { $files_list{$_} } "$domain";
                }
            }
        }
        elsif ($. >= 6) {
            print { $files_list{$file_name} } "$_";
        }
     }
    close(MYFILE1);
    foreach my $val (values %files_list) { close($val); }
    closedir $dir;
}

main_process;
```

This script creates files in the current directory based upon the content of `file.txt`, and then open those files again.

Then it starts processing `file.txt` and redirects the lines according to the filename set dynamically.

This setting of the file name is also based upon the data in the file `file.txt`.

The problem that I am facing here is that the redirection is only to a single file. That means there is some problem with the file handle.

All the files that are expected to be created are created perfectly but the data goes into only one of them.

I doubt if there is a problem with the file handle that I am using while redirecting.

Could anyone please help?
Sample input file is below:

```
..cnai #Generated on Thu Aug 02 18:33:18 2012 by CNAI R21D06_EC01, user tcssrpi
..capabilities BASIC
.utctime 2012-08-02 13:03:18
.subnetwork ONRM_ROOT_MO:NETSim_BAG
.domain BSC
.set BAG01
AFRVAMOS="OFF"
AWBVAMOS="OFF"
ALPHA=0
AMRCSFR3MODE=1,3,4,7
AMRCSFR3THR=12,21,21
AMRCSFR3HYST=2,3,3
AMRCSFR3ICM=
AMRCSFR4ICM=
USERDATA=""
.set BAG02
AFRVAMOS="OFF"
AWBVAMOS="OFF"
ALPHA=0
AMRCSFR3MODE=1,3,4,7
AMRCSFR3THR=12,21,21
AMRCSFR3HYST=2,3,3
..end
```

The problem that i am facing is during execution:

```
> process.pl 
Use of uninitialized value in ref-to-glob cast at process.pl line 79, <MYFILE1> line 6.
Can't use string ("") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at process.pl line 79, <MYFILE1> line 6.
```

The problem i can understand is with this line:

```
print { $files_list{$_} } "$domain";
```

but i am unable to understand why!!

The output i need is :

```
> cat NETSim_BAGBAG01.text 
.set BAG01
AFRVAMOS="OFF"
AWBVAMOS="OFF"
ALPHA=0
AMRCSFR3MODE=1,3,4,7
AMRCSFR3THR=12,21,21
AMRCSFR3HYST=2,3,3
AMRCSFR3ICM=
AMRCSFR4ICM=
USERDATA=""


> cat NETSim_BAGBAG02.text
.set BAG02
AFRVAMOS="OFF"
AWBVAMOS="OFF"
ALPHA=0
AMRCSFR3MODE=1,3,4,7
AMRCSFR3THR=12,21,21
AMRCSFR3HYST=2,3,3
>
```

Comment: Regarding your new problem *Use of uninitialized value in ref-to-glob cast*. There is no line 96 in the code you show so we can't really help properly, but the error is almost certainly because you have an undefined element value in your `%files_list` hash. Your code is very convoluted and awkward to read and I have given you an understandable working alternative in nearly a quarter of the lines that yours takes. It produces the exact output that you say you want. Please use it.

Comment: @Borodin.I have pasted the actual code

Comment: You have also changed the error you are reporting. This one is because one of the elements in you `%files_list` hash has a value of `""` - a null string. This is a wild goose chase. Please throw away this mess and use the working program that I gave you that solves the problem in 27 lines

Comment: As i said i am a beginner in perl .I want to learn from my mistakes.May be your script is running fine(i havent tested it.)But i too wanted to know my mistakes.After all,people learn from thier mistakes.Not By copying others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem in following lines:

```
open(PLOT,">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
$files_list{$_}=*PLOT;
```

You should replace they with:

```
open($files_list{$_},">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
```

Answer (score 3):

This portion of your code is the key:

```
 open(PLOT,">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
 $files_list{$_}=*PLOT;
```

The problem is that you are essentially using the filehandle PLOT as a global variable; every single entry in your hash is pointing to this same filehandle.  Replace with something like this:

```
 local *PLOT;
 open(PLOT,">>$_") || die("This file will not open!");
 $files_list{$_}=*PLOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got youself very entangled with this program. There is no need for the hash table or the multiple subroutines.

Here is a quick refactoring of your code that works with your data and writes files `NETSim_BAG.BAG01.text` and `NETSim_BAG.BAG02.text`. I put a dot between the subnet and the set to make the names a little clearer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $out_fh;
open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
my ($subnetwork, $set, $file);

while (<$fh>) {

    if ( /^\.subnetwork\s+\w+:(\w+)/ ) {
      $subnetwork = $1;
    }
    elsif ( /^\.set\s+(\w+)/ and $subnetwork) {
      $set = $1;
      $file = "$subnetwork.$set.text";
      open $out_fh, '>', $file or die qq(Unable to open "$file" for output: $!);
      print $out_fh;
    }
    elsif ( /^\.\.end/ ) {
      undef $subnetwork;
      undef $file;
    }

    if (/^[^.]/ and $file) {
      print $out_fh $_;
    }
}
```